# How safe is it to cache a user ticket in SESSION

Tags: php, api, authentication

I'm working on a client library to interface with my company's api, and we generate a user ticket when the user logs in using the api.

Obviously I don't want to send the user ticket to the client for resubmission on subsequent requests - is it (relatively) safe for me to cache this value in `$_SESSION` for later calls?

Comment: Highly depends on the implementation. `$_SESSION` is build around the session cookie (by default) and that's what you should protect first. Tell us a bit more on how you would approach this, as is there isn't enough info for a good answer.

Comment: Heh as I've been fleshing out the documentation this morning I realized that this is mostly an academic question; the only place I'm using it is in my simplified sample code, which won't be used in production.  That said, my practice if I were consuming the library in production would be to mark the cookies HTTPOnly and Secure. Depending on the usage I potentially use some header comparison to reject hijacked sessions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't be. The biggest consideration that I can see is you don't want your data being clobbered by the other code that is using the session. My common practice in this instance is to create a session key of `__{$company_name}` and store all of my bits there. This drastically reduces the chance that some other code will nuke my session variables.